# Using aspect-ratio in css with "calc"

Tags: css

I have a div with this css rule:

```
.somediv {
aspect-ratio: 1 / 3 !important;
}
```

I want to make the height equal not exactly (3 * width), but plus 8 pixels. For example, if my width is 10px, the height have to be like (10*3)+8 = 38 pixels. How can i do this, i know about calc() in css, but not sure it works with aspect-ratio.

Comment: `padding-top: 8px`? What's the context to the DOM hierarchy? Answers can depend heavily on it.

Comment: you can wrap it with another div with that extra 8 pixel

Comment: you will need javascript to retrieve the width, then do the calculation , then reset your aspect-ratio via style or setProperty() . ... i guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are to set a fixed width , you may use CSS var() to set the width, then use calc() for aspect-ratio

examples

```css
:root {
  --width: 80;
}

div {
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid;
  width: calc(var(--width) * 1px);
  aspect-ratio: var(--width) / calc(var(--width) * 3 + 8);
  
  
/* demo purpose */
  float: left;
}

div:before{
content:attr(style);
```

```html
<div>défault</div>
<div style="--width:100"> </div>
<div style="--width:101"> </div>
<div style="--width:70"> </div>
<div style="--width:90"> </div>
```

If width is not, then javascriipt will be required

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `padding-top` on the element you are styling for its size. It's counter intuitive because the size is supposedly ruled by the element `width` and its `aspect-ratio` but as you can see here in this demo, I show the computed width and height of the elements inside an `::after` pseudo element through a data attribute I set via javascript with the actual `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`.

Given the `width` as `100px` the height is indeed `width*3 + 8px = 308px`

```js
const target = document.querySelector('div');
target.dataset['width'] = `${target.offsetWidth}px*${target.offsetHeight}px`;
```

```css
.width-100{
  width: 100px;
}

.ratio-1over3 {  
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 3;  
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.outline{
  outline: solid red;
}

.ratio-1over3::after {  
  content: attr(data-width);
  display: block;      
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio-1over3 width-100 outline">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two `<div>`, a parent, with the dimensions and the aspect ratio, and a child with the `calc()`:

```css
.somediv {
  width: 100%; /* or any width you want */
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 3 !important;
}

.somediv__inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv">
  <div class="somediv__inner"></div>
</div>
```